# Populate range when all I have is beginning and end

Tags: python-3.x

If I have the following:

ABC0001-ABC0004, what would be the most efficient to output ABC0001,ABC0002,ABC003,ABC0004?

I realize there is a range function in python but at first glance it only works with numbers.

Thanks

I have tried Range but it only seems to work for numbers, I am not experienced enough to do much more than that and googling is only returning stuff related to range.

Comment: I see a range of numbers, `[0, ..., 4]` padded to 4 digits that are being prefixed with the string `ABC-`. So maybe there's a few different simpler problems you could solve to achieve this using some of the tools you've already identified.

Comment: thank you, programming is not my field and while I am understanding more and more its still a struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a range and adding that to a prefix string.
The result of range can also be zfiled.
Here is a small example of how you might generate those values into a list.

```
prefix = "ABC"

range = range(1, 10)

output = []
for i in range:
    number = str(i).zfill(4)
    output.append(prefix + number)

print(output)
```

Comment: thank you, your code can get me going in the right direction. I am trying to avoid doing a lot of repetitive manual work at the office.